# RegEx on Google Forms: How to make Case Insensitive work?

Tags: google-forms, regex, data-validation

I have been wondering, how to use case insensitive regular expression for a response validation in a form where there are different possible answers?

I have tried:
`(name1|name2|name3)`
and it really works, but I want it to be case insensitive.

Is there an easiest way to make it Case Insensitive?

I did:

1. `[?i(name1|name2|name3)]` – it didn't work, and it accepts names that are not in the parenthesis.
2. `[?i](name1|name2|name3)` – same as what happened to number 1

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-capturing group to set flags, like this:

`(?i)(name1|name2|name3)`

See [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: I am trying to use this Google Forms (as is the OP), where this is not a valid regex. Last time asked, there was no case insensitivity support on Google Forms (see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/46001787/using-case-insensitive-notation-in-a-regular-expression-answer-is-apparently-not-valid?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

[?i]name1|name2|name3|

It worked on mine.

Comment: Thanks @Kin ^_^

Comment: That regex will match `iname1`, `?name1`, `name2`, `name3` and also an empty text string, but it will **not** match `name1`, `Name1`, `Name2` or `nAME3` as specified in the question. Square brackets `[]` signify a character class rather than a group.